# Cannot Retrieve Cloned Div elements

Tags: jquery, dom, clone

For a slider project, I want to reach a child div inside a cloned div, but it seems not working:

```
 <div class="slide">
  <div class='slidecaption'><h2>Slide Number 1</h2></div> 
 <div class='slidetext'><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit,</p></div>
 </div> 

 <div class="slide"> 
  <div class='slidecaption'><h2>Slide Number 2</h2></div> 
 <div class='slidetext'><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit,</p></div>
 </div> 

 <div class="slide"> 
  <div class='slidecaption'><h2>Slide Number 3</h2></div> 
 <div class='slidetext'><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.</p></div>
 </div>
```

Now Jquery code is :

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
    var slides = $('.slide');   
    var firstclone = slides.eq(0).clone(true);
    var lastclone  = slides.eq(2).clone(true);

    slides.wrapAll('<div id="slideswrapper"></div>');
    firstclone.appendTo ("#slidesWrapper");
    lastclone.prependTo ("#slidesWrapper");
    var slidesNumber = slides.length;
 console.log(slidesNumber); //===> this will give 3 NOT 5
 console.log(slides); //===>this will give an object of only 3 divs
 console.log('#slidesWrapper'.html); //=====> this will give undefined 

});
```

Debugging the code will not show the expected result as commented in the code.
Now, as I understood from Jquery Documentation, any cloned div that inserted to the dom will be part of the dom, So Why I cannot get it right here , I mean 5 slides or the required html.

I want to retrieve the .slideText and .slideCaption content to manipulate them and add some effects.

Comment: `console.log('#slidesWrapper'.html); //=====> this will give undefined`
you call .html on a string here

Comment: `var slidesNumber = slides.length;`. Appending to the DOM doesn't change the contents of `slides`, you have to do `slides = $('.slide');` again.

Comment: Yes Barmar, this solved one issue thank you, but still cannot reach children divs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to re-select the elements.

At the time you're calling `var slides = $('.slide');`, there are indeed only 3 slides.

But if you run the selector again once the elements have been inserted, (`console.log($('.slide').length);`), you'll get 5 as expected.

Also, your code has typos, most importantly: `slidesWrapper` != `slideswrapper`.

Comment: but still cannot reach ('#slidesWrapper'.children)